# Why the weight force is not included in this free-body diagram

Tags: forces, statics

Take a look at this question.

[image]

The solution by the author is

[image]

**My question** is why the weight force is ignored in the free-body diagram? Is it because the roller(A) and the pint(B) which cancel the effect of the gravitational force?

Comment: It must be that the weight of the member is assumed to be negligible.

Comment: @BobD, that actually possible. Unfortunately, nothing stated in the question. Also, this chapter talks about free-body diagram so I've assumed I have to include all forces acting on the body.

Comment: Since it wasn't stated you need to assume so. You assume correctly. A FBD must include all forces, including weight. You can't determine reactions at the pin and roller otherwise. The roller and pin vertical reaction must equal the weight as well as the vertical component of the 390  lb force.

Comment: Where did the 390 lb come from?  I would take the y-component of that as the weight. And, therefore, the weight is used.

Comment: @jmh, well, may be an external force who knows except the author. But it seems the question is not very well written. Also, if this is the weight vector, why it is not drawn as an vertical downward vector?! I will go with BobD since the mass of the body is not mentioned.

Comment: @CroCo I would add that the drawing shows the beam to be uniform. Since the vertical member is shorter than the horizontal member, if the beam is  uniform the CG will be to the left of the vertical member not on top of it

Comment: @BobD;@CroCo, you both have convinced me. i have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be that the weight of the member is assumed to be negligible in comparison to the vertical component of the 390 lb force. With no information to the contrary you have to assume this to draw the FBD.

Also, you assume correctly that a FBD must include all forces, including weight. You can't determine reactions at the pin and roller otherwise. The sum of the roller and pin vertical reactions must equal the sum of the weight and the vertical component of the 390 lb force.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the fact that the drawing shows an extended body for all aspects of the system it seems wrong to conclude the object as massless!

Comment: @jmh I never said it was "massless". I said it must be assumed to be negligible. And what I mean by negligible is in comparison to the vertical component of the 390 lb force. In any case, if the member is uniform the CG would not be the point of application of the 390 lb force since the vertical member would only be 1/4 the weight of the horizontal member, assuming the members are uniform. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @jmh I would add it is not unusual to neglect the weight of the beam in elementary statics problems. What is unusual is for the problem not to state ignore the weight of the beam. That’s where this problem falls short